# How to choose between monomorphisation and type erasure for generics?

Tags: generics, monomorphization, type-erasure

Generic functions in compiled languages can be implemented in (at least) two different ways:

- [Monomorphisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphization) ─ separate versions of the function are compiled for each different assignment of type parameters. Essentially the function declaration is treated like a template for generating specialised code for each call site (though of course the code can be shared between multiple call sites with the same type parameters).
- [Type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) ─ the generic function is compiled to a single function, which works polymorphically for any type parameters.

What practical differences are there between these two choices, beyond the internal implementation details of the compiler ─ i.e., what differences are visible to users of the language? When would one be preferred to the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few differences between monomorphisation and type erasure:

- **Performance:** Monomorphisation generally leads to better runtime performance because each specialised version of the function is optimised for the specific types used at the call site. This can result in more efficient code and eliminate the need for dynamic dispatch. On the other hand, type erasure can introduce some overhead due to dynamic dispatch or runtime type checks.
- **Code Size:** Monomorphisation can increase the code size of the compiled program because it generates separate versions of the function for each type combination used. This could lead to some performance implications, but usually this is cancelled out by the fact that each version of the function is optimised for the specific type, as mentioned above. Type erasure, generating a single function only, generally leads to smaller code size.
- **Compilation Time:** Monomorphisation requires compiling separate versions of the function for each type combination. This can significantly increase compilation time, especially if there are numerous combinations. Type erasure, on the other hand, can reduce compilation time since there's only one version of the function to compile.
- **Debugging and Error Messages:** Monomorphisation can provide more precise error messages and easier debugging experience because each specialised version of the function has explicit types. Error messages can refer to specific types involved, aiding developers in identifying and fixing issues. In contrast, type erasure might provide less specific error messages since the function works polymorphically for any type parameters.

Comment: Monomorphisation can also increase the size of the compiled output ─ does this have implications for performance?

Comment: @kaya3 it could have some implications, but usually they are cancelled out by the fact that each version of the function is optimised for the specific types, as mentioned in the answer. That is a good point though, so I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Do you know if there is any empirical information about the performance differences? It's a good answer regardless, I'm just curious.

Comment: @kaya3 I'm sorry, but I don't know about that.

Answer (score 4):

One issue with type erasure is that it requires all possible types that the function might be called with, to have some fixed size in memory; in contrast, a monomorphised function can be specialised to types of different sizes.

In languages like Java, all or most types are the same size, because all values of those types are references to objects. However, even in Java primitive types can have different sizes, making it difficult or impossible to allow assigning primitive types to generic type parameters. This means e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>` is possible but `ArrayList<int>` isn't.

In contrast, monomorphisation allows for the size of the type parameters to be unconstrained, which is more flexible. This also means there is no need for boxed types like `Integer`, which have performance costs due to pointer indirection and memory management. Additionally, monomorphisation can save memory when the type parameter is a [zero-sized type](https://runrust.miraheze.org/wiki/Zero-sized_type), by not allocating memory for variables or fields whose values don't matter.

For example, a `HashTable<T, ()>` in Rust can be used to implement a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) without needing to allocate memory for the values in the hashtable. In Java, the equivalent code would allocate an array containing all `null` values, wasting space.

Comment: The size of the type does not need to be fixed for type erasure, it just needs to become an extra parameter to the type-erased function.  In general, all the type's attributes can become extra argument(s)

Comment: @ChrisDodd I suppose that's true, but then it also has to become an extra field on the object, and now not all `HashMap` objects have the same layout, which is problematic.

Comment: Only for objects that directly contain a field of a type-erased generic type, which is a different problem.  Even then, the type info can be stored in a separate metadata object rather than in the object directly, though that tends to favor implementations that support botth type-erased and monomorphic generics and can deal with either dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Monomorphization is less expressive than type erasure. The main limitation is that in order to monomorphize, the compiler must know the set of potential types. In some situations, this can be difficult or even impossible.

### When it's difficult

C++ has this somewhat [infamous quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) where all generics ("templates") have to be defined in the header, which defies the separation of [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) philosophy inherited from C. This is because in generics as implemented in C++ have to be instantiated before being converted to object code.

Rust has a similar issue with compilation of generics across different translation units ("crates"). Their solution is to [compile the generic functions into an intermediate language](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/hbml8s/how_can_rust_compile_crosscrate_generics/) instead of fully compiling them into object files where the generic structure would be lost.

### When it's impossible

Some kinds of generics are fundamentally incompatible with monomorphization because the underlying type is only known at run time. [Existential types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) are a classic example:

```
struct SortingAlgorithm {
  sort: forall<T> (less: (T, T) -> bool, array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
}
```

This is a structure holding a *generic* closure, but we don't know a priori what `T` is: the function pointer is required to accept *all* possible `T`.

Note: Rust `impl Trait` is sometimes referred to as "existential" but doesn't fully qualify as a proper existential type because it merely obscures the type without truly erasing it. For example, you can't put two `impl Trait` objects into a single `Vec<impl Trait>`; those two objects still have distinct types.

Answer (score 3):

### Why not a bit of both?

This is how Swift does it, AFAIK. for private/internal functions where it knows exactly how it’ll be called, it monomorphises. For public functions in a library and implementations of a protocol from a library, it uses type erasure. For performance, some functions in the standard library emit some monomorphised versions of functions for common types via the `@_specialize` attribute. See, for example, [`String.append(contentsOf:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/570c364cc4e6100a433d7d5d8c397279b7d27bbd/stdlib/public/core/StringRangeReplaceableCollection.swift#L162):

```swift
  @_specialize(where S == String)
  @_specialize(where S == Substring)
  @_specialize(where S == Array<Character>)
  public mutating func append<S: Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S)
  where S.Iterator.Element == Character
```

This emits monomorphised versions for `String`, `Substring`, and `Array<Character>`, but also a type-erased version that e.g. `Set<Character>` will use.

Comment: I want to use this mechanism, but I encountered a difficult problem. Generally speaking, the generic interface is defined by the library provider, and if the user wants to specialize a custom type, he cannot modify the code in the library.

Comment: @Aster Yep, that can be an issue — not necessarily for code generation, but for efficiency, since calls across module boundaries will always use the unspecialized version. IIRC Swift’s solution is to make all public generic functions implicitly `@inlineable`.